# 3D to nD representation of data

Tags: math

If I have three signals (e.g. data vectors vs. time), I can easily draw a 3D plot and the result surface helps me to see the relationship between the whole data in one single representation.
My question is how to extend this to n-dimensional?
I was thinking of n-dimensional Euclidean Space or something like hypersurfaces, but I am not sure which concept can help better. What I want finally is a representation of the data that can provide me with a relative behaviors. It can be so helpful, if I can just receive a hint.
(The data I am dealing with is coming from some algorithm which the input is a 10x2000 matrix and the output is a 10x2000 data as well. If you need I can provide data).

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to do this is to use a multiplot.  Basically you plot each pair of variables separately, then present them in a grid.

The book [Data Analysis with Open Source Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596802358) has a pretty good overview of this and other visualization techniques.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I checked the book, the problem is finally I want to compare two or more different representations (n-dimensional) against each other. I think some method like ANOVA can help. What do you suggest.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by compare.  If you're looking at ostensibly normally distributed variables and comparing means, there are multidimensional ANOVA methods.  If you don't know the distributions, you're probably better off sticking to either a graphical method or some type of regression or covariance.

Answer (score 0):

If the signals are completely uncorrelated with each other, the best way is to just plot on top of each other in 2D plots because they share no information between each other anyway.

If they are correlated in some way, you can use [Principle Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to reduce the dimensionality of your problem from nD to 3D or even less.  It is often used to visualize datasets.  That link gives wiki's over-complex definition, but [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html) can calculate it for you.